# Getting low on storage space error while using local database

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-8

I'm using `local database` to store my data. My code is based on a tutorial: [How to create a basic local database app for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202876%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) Everything was right, but I had to add some more data to my database and now when I'm trying to do so I get info "Your phone is low on storage space". Is it possible that my database is too big?

This is how I create my database:

```
using (TablesDataContext db = new TablesDataContext(TablesDataContext.DBConnectionString))
{
    if (db.DatabaseExists() == false)
    {
       //Create the database
        db.CreateDatabase();
    }
}
```

And my `DataContext`:

```
public class TablesDataContext : DataContext
    {
        // Specify the connection string as a static, used in main page and app.xaml.
        public static string DBConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/Customers.sdf";

        // Pass the connection string to the base class.
        public TablesDataContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        { }

        // Specify a single table for the to-do items.
        public Table<CustomerItem> CustomersTable;
        public Table<CategorieItem> CategoriesTable;
        public Table<ProductItem> ProductsTable;
        public Table<CustomerPricesItem> CustomerPricesTable;
    }
```

Comment: The default size is 32, but can be increased up to 512. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202861(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Have you tried using SD card instead of internal phone memory?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your phone have enough free storage space?

If your phone had enough free space, you can try to add the Max Database Size parameter in your connection string. By default, when you first create a Database, the size is set to 32Mb. Including the **Max Database Size** you can specify the desired size, with a max value of 512Mb:

```
"Data Source='isostore:/Db.sdf'; Max Database Size = 256;"
```

This way, the first time you create a Database using the above connection string, it max size is set to 256Mb.

Also, i know this is another problem, but if your writes are large sets of data, you could want to add to the connection string the **Max Buffer Size** parameter, with a max value of 5120 (5Mb) it represent the amount of data stored in memory before proceed to write to disk... it can speed your writes:

```
"Data Source='isostore:/Db.sdf'; Max Database Size = 256; Max Buffer Size = 3072;"
```

If your data is bigger tan that, maybe you need to Split it in different files or use another Database as SQLite.

What data are you storing in the Database? Images? only text... binary files... Maybe there is a better way of opimizing the Database size, if you are storing images on a db field, maybe is better to store the image in the isolated storage and the path in the db.

Hope This help!